# iPad 2 has suddenly lost ALL Contacts, ALL Calendar entries

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, contacts, calendar

iPad 2 lost all Contacts, Calendars.

The data is still in iCloud and my iMac has all this information

I've tried Wi-Fi, iCloud, and syncing via iTunes, but can't retrieve information.

Comment: We have droves of questions covering both losing all contacts and losing all calendars. Would you refine your issue with more details that would make it distinct from the ground already covered. Specifically, what count of contacts are stored when you log into http://icloud.com on a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Any one of the paths - WiFi syncing down from iCloud or choosing to sync contacts over iTunes should work to get contacts on your iPad.

Since it's the one device having problems, you will want to back it up and restore it to factory settings and test one set of data - perhaps contacts from iCloud.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414

At the end of the steps linked above - choose to set up as new and then text contacts. This isn't a definite answer since you'll need to troubleshoot a bit, but it's a start on that process.